# Budget PC Build for Blender 2.8

Tags: hardware

I'm planning to build a pc for Blender 2.8, mainly for cycles rendering and sculpting. Will this build be sufficient for the task and for long term use?

- Ryzen 7 2700
- Motherboard (supports crossfire)
- 32GB(3200) RAM
- 2x AMD RX580

Comment: In case of B3D you should care about the software rather than hardware. I mean OpenGL, Python etc.

Comment: See: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Answer (score 1):

IMO your question is incomplete.

> Will this build be sufficient for the task

Well, it depends. For sure you can use it, do renders, but it can take more time to complete the task compared to other systems.
Another thing to consider is if you will use things like physic simulations or particle systems.
Always keep in mind that an high poly count will increase render times, so you have to optimize your scene, especially with sculpted meshes.

> Budget PC

This can also be a questionable one.
What do you mean with budget? For someone it can be 500 dollars, for other people it can be 700. In this case even 150-200 dollars can make a nice improvement.
Anyway you can check some benchmarks to see what performs best in your price range.